# como realizo un multi delete

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo la siguiente query

```
          DELETE 
            Proyectos, 
            Observaciones, 
            Fechas_revisiones, 
            Residentes, 
            Revisores_anteproyectos,
            Validar_anteproyectos,
            Validar_proyecto
         FROM 
            Proyectos T1,
            Observaciones T2, 
            Fechas_revisiones T3,
            Residentes T4, 
            Revisores_anteproyectos T5,
            Validar_anteproyectos T6,
            Validar_proyecto T7
          WHERE
                T1.id='1234'
            AND T2.id_proyecto=T1.id
            AND T3.id_proyecto=T1.id
            AND T4.id_proyecto=T1.id
            AND T5.id_proyecto=T1.id
            AND T6.id_proyecto=T1.id
            AND T7.id_proyecto=T1.id
```

la ejecuto y me dice que desconoce la primera tabla

```
 #1109 - Unknown table 'Proyectos' in MULTI DELETE
```

no entiendo si esta bien escrito incluso copie el nombre desde el phpmyadmin
ayuda algo estoy haciendo mal existe una forma mas corta de llegar a borrar esos registros ojo que no estan como foreign key

Answer (score 1):

lo solucione con este query

```
           DELETE 
            T1, 
            T2,
            T3,
            T4,
            T5,
            T6,
            T7
           FROM 
             Proyectos T1

             JOIN Observaciones T2
            ON (T2.id_proyecto=T1.id)

             JOIN Fechas_revisiones T3
            ON(T3.id_proyecto=T1.id)

             JOIN Residentes T4
            ON(T4.id_proyecto=T1.id)

            JOIN Revisores_anteproyectos T5
            ON(T5.id_proyecto=T1.id)

             JOIN Validar_anteproyectos T6
            ON(T6.id_proyecto=T1.id)

             JOIN Validar_proyecto T7
            ON(T7.id_proyecto=T1.id)
          WHERE
                T1.id='1234'
```